# Setting up git for development and production

Tags: git, version-control, architecture

I am using below mentioned life cycle to push any changes or feature on production.

Localhost (Developers work on localhost) -> migrate their changes to staging (for QA - Changes of more than 1 developer can be there) -> Production.

Here is the workflow which i am using,

```
-master(runs on production)
 -staging (runs on staging server - parent master)
  -feature (parent staging)
```

Developers work on feature branch and merge it back to staging.

The issue here which i am facing is there can be more than 1 developers code in the  staging, if i want to go live with code of 1 developer i can not merge staging directly into master nor i can merge feature into master as it is child of staging, it can have code of staging which are not live yet and not to be pushed.

Need help to define proper git workflow. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a workflow before which is similar to the situation you described above in your question.  Here is a brief outline of that workflow:

- One or more developers will work on any number of feature branches.  Each feature branch will be created from `master` at the beginning of each sprint.
- At the end of the sprint, when all features are completed, each feature branch is merged into `staging`.  Staging also will initially be created from `master`.  You can give the staging branch a unique name to refer to it easily, e.g. `staging_05_15` for the May, 2015 branch.
- The final week of each sprint will be spent testing the `staging` branch to make sure that it is stable.  If all features in the `staging` branch are OK and tests pass, then `staging` will be released to the customer.
- Finally, `staging` is merged back into `master`, and the cycle repeats again for the next sprint.

Comment: I have tried the solution you have mentioned. but when i create a feature branch from master and try to merge it to staging. It shows more no of modified files than actual modified files. this looks to be because master is behind staging at any instance.

Comment: Yes, `master` will get behind `staging` during the course of a sprint, but this is by design and is unavoidable.  You should be merging in this order: `feature` -> `staging` -> `master`.